# Discord.py Economy command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making an economy command for my bot. The error I believe is in the `open_account()` function. When you run the balance command it sees that I do not have an account and writes into the JSON file as it should but does not send the embed. I checked the embed and it works fine. It's something before calling the embed. Also, the beg command does not add the amount you make to the JSON file. I've spent days trying to understand what the problem is with no luck. Anyone can help me figure out where I messed up?

```py
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()


    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    embed=discord.Embed(title="{}s balance:".format(member.name), color=0xe20303)
    embed.add_field(name="Wallet:", value=wallet_amt, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Bank:", value=bank_amt, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users


@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    earnings = random.randrange(2000)

    if earnings == 0:
        await ctx.send(f"How unlucky... You didn't get anything...")

    elif earnings > 50:
        await ctx.send(f"Nice you got ${earnings} from a cool dude")

    elif earnings > 100:
        await ctx.send(f"Someone felt nice and gave you ${earnings}")

    elif earnings > 500:
        await ctx.send(f"You seem to have a way with people! Someone gave you ${earnings}")

    elif earnings > 800:
        await ctx.send(f"What a lucky day!! Someone gave you ${earnings}")

    elif earnings > 1500:
        await ctx.send(f"A rich man passed by you and felt bad. So ha gave you ${earnings}")

    elif earnings > 2000:
        await ctx.send(f"A shady man walked up to you and said 'I know how tough it can be out here' before giving you ${earnings}")


    users[srt(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
```

Comment: I now think the error is within `wallet = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]` and `bank = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]`. I cleared them out and put "test" for the embed value and it worked. I'm guessing the error is within the process of getting the wallet and bank number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove `await` and `async` from get_bank_data & open_account 
 Second you need to give  `user = ctx.author` into balance 
 Third you need to repair your typo in beg command `users[srt(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings` into `users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings` 
 Fourth you need to use

```
with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
```

instead

```
with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
```

And that's it. It should work, if not you can write under this Answer and we can edit it.

E: 
 Also I used `embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}s balance:", color=0xe20303)` in balance

Answer (score 0):

Functions open_account and get_bank_data are no asynchronous functions. Try to remove the async/await before them.

Comment: Now it won't add a user to the account. Also got an error `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'open_account' was never awaited open_account(ctx.author)`

Comment: Ah okay. Could it be you are missing a `user = ctx.author`? In `wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]` and `bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]` `user` is undefined. Also i don't understand where `member` should be defined.

Comment: For the second problem: First there is a typo in `users[srt(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings` and second, you have to write ("w") and dump users, not read ("r") and load.

Answer (score 0):

Also, at the beginning try spacing the `async def balance(ctx):await open_account(ctx.author)` the await open_account should be on a different line.

Answer (score 0):

In the third last line, you misspelled `str` as srt

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved the problem yet, but the problem lies within the balance command, define the variable user as ctx.author just like you did in the beg command. Then you have an typo within where you add the earnings to the account, all you have to do is change that to str. That’s all I see is wrong with the code.